# String manipulation in haskell

Tags: arrays, string, haskell

I've been coding in Java and Python last 3,4 years. Now I decided I want to learn Haskell.

I have a string in the form:

> "https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all"

I need a function that would increment page number:

> "https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=all"

and this string to:

> "https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=3&tab=reputation&filter=all"

and so on...

I'm very new to Haskell and don't know how to manipulate strings. How to write such a function?

Comment: A string in Haskell is a list of characters (sounds familiar?) Consider `Data.Char.isDigit`. And perhaps a `filter`.

Comment: Hint: all values in Haskell are immutable, so you won't be able to actually change the string. You'll have to construct a new one.

Comment: This question is too broad however. Pick up a Haskell book. [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is popular, and can be read online for free. After the first few chapters you should be able to answer this for yourself.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm currently reading first chapters of this book. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the exact position of the number in the `String` I would recommend using a function

```
stoverString :: Int -> String
stoverSTring n = "http://stackoverflow.com/users?page="++ show n
               ++"&tab=reputation&filter=all"
```

and then use `map` in combination with [Int] to create all the `String`s you desire.

Assuming you want to do some downloading - the next function you should look into is `mapM` a relative of the simple `map` function that does IO-actions with your list, instead of simple function application for each element of the list.